# Is there a way to get the username of the currently authenticated user in python Bottle using basic_auth?

Tags: python, basic-authentication, bottle

I would like to display the currently authorized user in a python Bottle session, where I am using basic_auth for the authorization framework.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I haven't used Bottle specifically, but many auth systems will put the username in the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

```
user = request.auth[0]
```

or

```
user = request.environ.get('REMOTE_USER')
```

Comment: Both of these worked perfectly - thanks!  I ended up using the first one, as I thought it was a little clearer/cleaner.

Comment: Good to hear! +1 for using the first one; I agree that it's preferable.